# How to create a condition to assign admin role to a new user on meteor?

Tags: javascript, meteor

So I'm playing around with meteor. I've created a simple app and added alanning:roles package to be able to have different user roles.

I have this page in my admin environment to create a new user, and I want to add a checkbox to assign a user role to the user before creating. The template html (create-user.html) looks like this:

```
<template name="AdminCreateUser">
    <body>
        {{> _adminNav }}
        <section class="container main">
        <h1>Hmmm...trying to create a user?</h1>
        <form>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
                <input type="email" class="form-control" id="registerEmail" placeholder="Email">
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Password</label>
                <input type="password" class="form-control" id="registerPassword" placeholder="Password">
              </div>
              <div class="checkbox">
                <label>
                  <input type="checkbox" {{checked}} class="toggle-checked"> This is an admin
                </label>
              </div>
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
            </form>
      </section>
    </body>
</template>
```

The page JS (create-user.js) is something like this:

```
Template.AdminCreateUser.events({
    'submit form': function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var emailVar = event.target.registerEmail.value;
        var passwordVar = event.target.registerPassword.value;
        Accounts.createUser({
            email: emailVar,
            password: passwordVar
        });
        }
});
```

How can I make this checkbox to change the user role for the user that I am creating? I was thinking on making an IF statement to check if it's checked. But I'm having doubts on how/where to create that if statement and where to place the user role in the JS code.

BTW: all this code is in my CLIENT/views/admin folder. Is it there where they're supposed to be?

Thanks guys.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the official documentation here: http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/accounts_passwords

Put a callback inside your createUser function call. Your code on client side is fine as it also directly logs the user in on successful creation of the account. You can then use the profile attribute of currentUser to set your own custom roles. In this case check how alanning:roles defines those.

You can create an if statement checking the value of your checkbox and if checked setting the role like this for example if you would use the regular profile to set a role.

currentUser.profile.role = 'admin';

I had a look and found that with your package this function call can be made after a successful createUser call:

```
if(user.roles.length > 0){
   // Need _id of existing user record so this call must come 
   // after `Accounts.createUser` or `Accounts.onCreate`
   Roles.addUsersToRoles(id, user.roles, 'default-group');
}
```

More examples and documentation: https://github.com/alanning/meteor-roles

Answer (score 0):

We need to findout if the checked button retrieve true/false value from checkbox 
 I didnt tested these but try to put log if variable X if there's any value. If true or check it can create Admin but false it can create Normal User
    `Template.AdminCreateUser.events({
    'submit form': function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var emailVar = event.target.registerEmail.value;
        var passwordVar = event.target.registerPassword.value;
        var x = $(event.target).is(":checked").val();
        if(x){
           id = Accounts.createUser({
            email: emailVar,
            password: passwordVar
          });
         Roles.addUsersToRoles(id, ['admin'], 'default-group');
        }else{
            id = Accounts.createUser({
            email: emailVar,
            password: passwordVar
          });
            Roles.addUsersToRoles(id, ['user'], 'default-group');
         }
    });`

Note: I didn't tested these code but i think i can help you.